# categorical data with D3 scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, scale, ordinal

I am trying to plot the data with d3. My data looks like this:

```
dataset = [
["HBO", 23, "tv show"],
["HBO", 45, "movie"],
["Hulu", 40, "tv show"],
["Hulu", 56, "movie"]
]
```

I am using `scaleLinear()` for numerical data `(d[1])` and `scaleBand()` for categorical data.
Here is my code:

```js
const dataset = [
  ["HBO", 23, "tv show"],
  ["HBO", 45, "movie"],
  ["Hulu", 40, "tv show"],
  ["Hulu", 56, "movie"]
];

const width = 600, height = 400;
const padding = 20, marginTop = 50;

// Min and max for y axis for Revenue values
const maxRevenue = d3.max(dataset, (d) => d[1]);
const minRevenue = d3.min(dataset, (d) => d[1]);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([minRevenue, maxRevenue])
  .range([height - padding, marginTop]);

const xScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain([dataset, (d) => d[2]])
  .range([0, 100]);

const rScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain([dataset, (d) => d[2]])
  .range([3, 3]);

// positioning the whole chart
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d[2]))
  .attr("cy", (d) => yScale(d[1]))
  .attr("r", (d) => rScale(d[2]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The expected output is the screenshot below. My code doesn't display the circles...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, you used `[dataset, (d) => d[2]]`, but that doesn't do anything. Well, it creates an array of a dataset and a function, but that's not what you wanted.

To actually create the array that you want (`["tv show", "movie", "tv show", "movie"]`), you need to call `dataset.map((d) => d[2])` yourself:

```js
const dataset = [
  ["HBO", 23, "tv show"],
  ["HBO", 45, "movie"],
  ["Hulu", 40, "tv show"],
  ["Hulu", 56, "movie"]
];

const width = 600, height = 400;
const padding = 20, marginTop = 50;

// Min and max for y axis for Revenue values
const maxRevenue = d3.max(dataset, (d) => d[1]);
const minRevenue = d3.min(dataset, (d) => d[1]);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([minRevenue, maxRevenue])
  .range([height - padding, marginTop]);

const xScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  // You need to actually call `Array.prototype.map` yourself
  .domain(dataset.map((d) => d[2]))
  .range([0, 100]);

const rScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(dataset.map((d) => d[2]))
  .range([3, 3]);

// positioning the whole chart
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d[2]))
  .attr("cy", (d) => yScale(d[1]))
  .attr("r", (d) => rScale(d[2]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```